# Is Tensorflow Serving example expected to have 10% error rate?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I followed the docs [Building an optimized serving binary](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/building_with_docker.md#building-an-optimized-serving-binary) then [Testing the development environment](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/building_with_docker.md#testing-the-development-environment), and I got

> Inference error rate: 10.4%

Is it expected that a fresh install of a release build of TensorFlow Serving would give a 10% error rate on the provided example model?

My environment:

```
AWS EC2
OS: Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
Instance Type: r5.large
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
# download tensorflow serving code
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving
cd serving
# build optimized serving binary
docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel   -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
# run & open shell for generated docker image
docker run -it -p 8600:8600 ec2-user/tensorflow-serving-devel:latest
# train the mnist model
python tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py /tmp/mnist_model
# serve the model
tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --model_name=mnist --model_base_path=/tmp/mnist_model/ &
# test the client
python tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py --num_tests=1000 --server=localhost:8500
```

Comment: I see now that my confusion was thinking the error rate was a problem getting predictions from tensorflow serving.  I'm an engineer, not a data scientist. The mnist_client.py code actually lumps together communication errors and inaccurate predictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example mnist_saved_model.py as part of tensorflow_serving's example is more focused on speed to create a model and a simple example on how to save a model then accuracy.

In https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_advanced, it shows that when the above code is trained with 100 iterations it has a 13.1% error rate, and when trained with 2000 iterations it has a 9.5% error rate.

The default if `--training_iteration` is not specified is 1000, so your 10.4 error rate is inline with these results.

You will find this mnist model provides better accuracy (and takes much longer to train): https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/mnist

This model will work with the slight changes to the mnist_client.py example.

try this:

## train the mnist model

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PWD/models"
pushd models/official/mnist/
python mnist.py --export_dir /tmp/mnist_model
```

## serve the model

`tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --model_name=mnist --model_base_path=/tmp/mnist_model/ &`

## switch back the original directory

`popd`

## make the follow changes to mnist_client.py to work with the new model

```
diff --git a/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py b/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py
index 592969d..85ef0bf 100644
--- a/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py
+++ b/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py
@@ -112,8 +112,8 @@ def _create_rpc_callback(label, result_counter):
       sys.stdout.write('.')
       sys.stdout.flush()
       response = numpy.array(
-          result_future.result().outputs['scores'].float_val)
-      prediction = numpy.argmax(response)
+          result_future.result().outputs['classes'].int64_val)
+      prediction = response[0]
       if label != prediction:
         result_counter.inc_error()
     result_counter.inc_done()
@@ -143,9 +143,9 @@ def do_inference(hostport, work_dir, concurrency, num_tests):
   for _ in range(num_tests):
     request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
     request.model_spec.name = 'mnist'
-    request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict_images'
+    request.model_spec.signature_name = 'classify'
     image, label = test_data_set.next_batch(1)
-    request.inputs['images'].CopyFrom(
+    request.inputs['image'].CopyFrom(
         tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image[0], shape=[1, image[0].size]))
     result_counter.throttle()
     result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)  # 5 seconds
```

## test the client

`python tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py --num_tests=1000 --server=localhost:8500`

```
Inference error rate: 0.8%
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is Tensorflow Serving an example expected to have a 10% error rate?

Yes, this particular example is expected to have a 10% error rate as the accuracy of this model on training and testing data is almost the same (around 90%) i.e., this is a very basic neural network as shown [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py).

If you want a good prediction accuracy, you might have to use [resnet_client.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/resnet_client.py) or you can actually add more layers and tune the hyper-parameters to get higher prediction accuracy or lesser inference error rate.

A tutorial on how to use the resent model to serve is given [here](https://medium.com/tensorflow/serving-ml-quickly-with-tensorflow-serving-and-docker-7df7094aa008). This should give you a much lesser inference error rate.